# Cleaning xml document from wrong data

Tags: .net, xml

Logging subsystem writes log in xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<log version="1.0">    
<message time="2011-04-11 17:10:10.0020" class="info">
la la la la..
</message>
```

I assume that writing in login file may crashes. In result xml log file may contain wrong xml data strings

for example

```
<message ti
```

Is exist convenient way of clearing xml file from wrong data parts,except of using regexp?

upd:wrong data parts can occur in middle of file not only in the end.

Comment: Look for 'tolerant' parsers. The XMLUnit project has such a feature for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great reason not to use XML as a logging format.  Even without crashes, the log is *never* well-formed XML, since you never close the root tag.

As to how to clean it?  Assuming you only get truncated files, read in the file, look for the last `"</message>"`, truncate there, add a `"</log>"`, and try to parse it.

Comment: i assume that wrong messages(broken messages) can occur in middle of xml log not only in the end

Comment: I am extending existing logging system. The base idea is: writing in xml for easy parsing.

Comment: I think you're finding that "easy parsing" is out the window.  I think you'd be better off with a format more suited to streaming and resynchronizing in the face of errors.